# How to indicate a class in HTML label tag

Tags: html, class, label, indicator

Here is some code to understand the question.

```
<body>
    <h2>This is form tutorial.</h2>
    <form action="backend.php">
        <label for="name">Name:</label>
        <div>
            <input type="text" name="myName" id="name">
        </div>
    </form>
</body>
```

So my question is in the line `<label for="name">Name:</label>` the `for="name"` line indicates the label `Name:`  goes to the `div` which has the id `name` but is it possible to use the label tag in which the label will go to all the classes with the specified class

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HTML provides no means to associate a label with elements using a class.

A label is designed to label a **single** form control.

An ID identifies a **single** element.

A class groups **multiple** elements.

It makes sense for labels to use IDs for association, but it wouldn't make sense to use class for that.

If you want to group multiple form controls with a "label" then use a fieldset with a legend instead.

```
<fieldset>
    <legend>Name</legend>
    <input name="given-name" id="given-name"> <label for="given-name">Given name</label> 
    <br>
    <input name="family-name" id="family-name"> <label for="family-name">Family name</label> 
</fieldset>
```

(Although I use names for this example, it is a bit contrives and you should [be aware of some of the issues programmers have dealing with names](https://www.kalzumeus.com/2010/06/17/falsehoods-programmers-believe-about-names/) before doing anything involving them).

Comment: Ok so there can only be one id with a specific name but there can can be many classes with the same name is that so?

Comment: Yes. IDs **must** be unique in a document.

Comment: So will i get a error if i keep two ids with same name

Comment: If you use a validation tool you will. Browsers' won't throw an error as they are designed to cope with bad HTML quietly. You might get unexpected behaviour with things not working the way you expect though.